# Selenium - Unable to find a free port

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, freebsd

I'm running an app that depends on selenium on FreeBSD server.
During the startup I've got the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.findFreePort(PortProber.java:67) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
```

I've found some solutions on the internet that the entries which contains 'localhost' should be removed from the hosts file, but I don't have a permission to do that.

Do you know how to fix the problem without modifying /etc/hosts file?

Answer (score 1):

Check your JAVA_HOME pointing to some shared drive. If you run your Selenium test from Eclipse IDE, check in Eclipse > Window > Preference > Java > Installed JRE. The active (tick mark selected) should point to local drive's JRE path (Check the column 'Location'). If not, then add local JRE from C:\Program Files\Java\JDK path. Restart your IDE and run now. BINGO!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without changing the localhost

First get the process id name by greping port no 1024

```
ps -aux | grep 1024
```

And then kill that process

```
kill -9 PROCESS_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you are running your scripts on remote server. Then make sure about few points:

1. Always close or quit your browser after every test run.
2. Just in case if point one doesn't work then increase the PORT RANGE on your remote server.

Comment: Can you explain why closing the browser helps and how to increase the port range?

Answer (score 0):

I found free port not an exception in run time, so I went to windows>> preferences>>jre installed >> add >> standard VM >> directory>> the software saved folder is empty, now how I can find the path

Answer (score 0):

ps -ax | grep chrome - find all active chrome. Driver instance

kill 5597 10757 10758 10761 10773 10915 - kill the process ids

Uncomment /etc/hosts file localhost and broadcasthost like below,

127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost