# Is there any way to solve "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port" issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, runtimeexception

I am using Jenkins, Maven, and Chromedriver to execute selenium scripts but while running multiple projects at same time it is giving me this error.
How can we solve this issue?
I have scheduled multiple scripts on jenkins and which are executed when code is pushed to git.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port
>       at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.findFreePort(PortProber.java:67)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:351)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:157)
>       at Check.Status.Tests.driverSetup(Tests.java:33)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Unable to find a free port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858790/selenium-unable-to-find-a-free-port)

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port
```

...is a [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) which is the superclass of those exceptions that can be thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine.

---

### Protecting the ports that chromedriver use

There is nothing much we can do about the port usage as @barancev [mentions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5211#issuecomment-387217247) *ChromeDriver* attempts to find a free [Ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) using a system-dependent ephemeral port range detector. An [ephemeral port](https://pubs.vmware.com/view-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.view.installation.doc%2FGUID-0E9C03E8-D85F-4325-908B-9CD390EC21E9.html) is a short-lived endpoint that is created by the operating system when a program requests any available user port. The operating system selects the port number from a predefined range, typically between 1024 and 65535, and releases the port after the related TCP connection terminates.

By default, the system can create a maximum of approximately 4,000 ephemeral ports that run concurrently on Windows Server 2003 and approximately 16,000 on Windows Server 2008.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How do I protect the ports that chromedriver use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442679/how-do-i-protect-the-ports-that-chromedriver-use/55450099#55450099)

---

### Issue in details

- As per @visionscaper's [comment](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1630#issuecomment-256922339) on *Windows* systems you need to **remove** / **comment out** the following type of entries from **`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`** file:

  ```
  127.0.0.1 my-site.local
  192.168.100.48 localhost
  ```
- As per @DavidGDD's [comment](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1630#issuecomment-304682673) on *Linux* systems in `PortProber.java` and `LinuxEphemeralPortRangeDetector.java` there is a case in `createAcceptablePort` in which is always returning the same port, not random.

  - When you have defined in the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` the port range as `1024-65535`, the method always returns **1024**.
  - When you change your range defined in the file to `1025-65535` (or any other range) it will work returning random ports.
- @tflori [mentions](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1630#issuecomment-442857566) from [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) point of view:

  - [LinuxEphemeralPortRangeDetector.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/net/LinuxEphemeralPortRangeDetector.java#L49) had more than one space between the two ports. So the result was `[1025, , , , 65535]` then `Integer.parseInt(split[1]);` throws and the default is used which leads to the same issue we had without modifying the lower port.
  - [PortProber.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/net/PortProber.java#L88) we were geting the highest and lowest ports from the platform and then we overwrite one or the other 1024 or 65535.

---

### Solution

This [merge](https://github.com/softagram/selenium/pull/1) solves the port negotiation problem on linux and other platforms. The removed code leads to the result that FIRST_PORT and LAST_PORT is both set to 1024 which always returns 1024. In fact we should trust the ephemeral ports reports by the detector. With the min and max we just assure a valid port range. So you need to ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 77.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v77.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.