# Alright am Trying to run a Java file containing selenium libaray and I get a "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port" error message

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-studio, selenium-chromedriver

Just as the title says but wait Here me out!
I'm a new Android developer and after hours of browsing the internet for solutions for my problem I couldn't find a single solution that actually guides me through the files and stuff so please
let's do this once and for all so more and more people won't small their hands on the table for help

Just wanted to mention the obvious question: I'm using Android Studio IDE not Eclipse or any other shit

[The whole Activity/Project + the error written in red below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os6fI.png)

Don't ignore please help me

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858790/selenium-unable-to-find-a-free-port#:~:text=Check%20your%20JAVA_HOME%20pointing%20to,Preference%20%3E%20Java%20%3E%20Installed%20JRE.&text=If%20not%2C%20then%20add%20local,your%20IDE%20and%20run%20now.

Comment: @Darshana I doesn't have help at all becase I'm using Android Studio IDE as I mentioned and not Eclipse

Comment: Okay, but we can kill port using another way like a command-line tool.

Comment: @Darshana could you inlabret I do not know how to do it

Comment: See accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows if you are a windows user. for other operating systems you can google the same.

Comment: @Darshana alright thanks, which ports I have to kill? 1024?

Comment: Which display with your error message, 7076

Comment: @Darshana It gave me the error "proccess '7076' not found"

Comment: kill 7076 -> return process 7076 not found?

Comment: @Darshana yep, just like that