# Unable to find a free port for ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

Seeing below error when trying to create an instance of ChromeDriver. Using Mac and eclipse for my first Selenium project.

Code Used:

```
WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        chromeDriver.get("https://www.selenium.dev");
        System.out.println(chromeDriver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(chromeDriver.getCurrentUrl());
```

Error Received:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.findFreePort(PortProber.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:441)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at SeIntro.main(SeIntro.java:12)
```

Comment: Have you tried these suggestions: [selenium-unable-to-find-a-free-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858790/selenium-unable-to-find-a-free-port)

Comment: @topsail Yes, nothing worked.